# Get array ids sequentially by elements filename/postname

Tags: php

I have an array that is not ordered sequentially by ID however the `[post_title]` which is essentially the file name and it does retain the sequential number based values.

How can I get the first element ID in an array then the second and so on but sequentially based off the number of the element `[post_name]` or `[post_title]`?

For Example:
get first array element id

```
$pmockupzero = current($media)->ID;
```

get second array element id

```
$pmockuponea = array_slice($media, 1, 1, true);
$pmockupone = current($pmockuponea)->ID;
```

But these do not take into account the sequential [post_name].

```
Array
(
[104682] => WP_Post Object
    (
        [ID] => 104682
        [post_title] => 45232-183.jpg
        [post_name] => 45232-183-jpg
    )
[104681] => WP_Post Object
    (
        [ID] => 104681
        [post_title] => 45232-182.jpg
        [post_name] => 45232-182-jpg
    )
[104679] => WP_Post Object
    (
        [ID] => 104679
        [post_title] => 45232-180.jpg  
        [post_name] => 45232-180-jpg
    )
[104680] => WP_Post Object
    (
        [ID] => 104680
        [post_title] => 45232-181.jpg
        [post_name] => 45232-181-jpg
    )
```

)

Comment: Why don't you sort your array by `post_name`?

Comment: If you want to process the array sequentially, just use a `foreach` loop.

Comment: yeah you can sort when you do the wp query

Answer (score 1):

You can use `uasort()` to provide your own sorting function for the array.

[PHP Manual - Arrays - uasort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php)

```php
uasort($media, function ($a, $b) {
    return strnatcmp($a->post_title, $b->post_title);
});

$first_item_by_title = current($media);
```

*note: I use natural string comparison so that title2 would sort ahead of title10*

[PHP Manual - Strings - Natural Comparison](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strnatcmp.php)